# How to subtract a value from the first element of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to subtract a number `x` from the first element of the array, and in case the first element in the array is smaller than `x` I want to subtract the remaining amount from the second element of the array and so on.

I have tried this:

```
import numpy as np

x = 25
y = np.array([22, 30, 45])
result = np.copy(y)

for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] < x:
        result[i] = y[i] - x
        x = x - y[i]
    else:
        result[i] = y[i] - x
        x = x - y[i]
```

I get this result:

```
array([-3, 27, 72])
```

But I want to have

```
array([0, 27, 45])
```

Comment: Is your expected output correct ?

Comment: -3 is less than 27. So why did the loop keep going. I am confused. Your problem statement and the example don't add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the `if` case, you should assign `0`
- In the `else` case there must be a `break` to stop as all value to remove has been consumed

```
def sub_array(array, to_remove):
    result = np.copy(array)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] < to_remove:
            result[i] = 0
            to_remove -= array[i]
        else:
            result[i] = array[i] - to_remove
            break
    return result
```

```
print(sub_array(np.array([10, 10, 10]), 39))  # [0  0  0]
print(sub_array(np.array([10, 10, 10]), 29))  # [0  0  1]
print(sub_array(np.array([10, 10, 10]), 19))  # [0  1 10]
print(sub_array(np.array([10, 10, 10]), 9))   # [1 10 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it so it only continues as long as z2>0:

```
for i in range(len(y2)):
    if  z2>0:
        result[i] = max(y2[i] - z2,0)
        z2 = z2 - y2[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```py
import numpy as np
x = 25
z = x
l= np.array([22, 30, 45])
i = 0

while(x>0 and i<len(l)):
    if x>=l[i]:
        x-=l[i]
        l[i]=0
    else:
        l[i]-=x
        x=-1
    z=x
    i+=1
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that first, `y2[i] - z2` is going to be negative, that's why you get the -3. The second problem is that when it goes into the else condition, it makes z2 negative. This creates a problem because `z2=-27` at that point, 45--27=72. You can try this solution:

```
import numpy as np
x2 = 25
y2= np.array([22, 30, 45])
z2 = x2
result = np.copy(y2)

for i in range(len(y2)):
    if y2[i] < z2:
        result[i] = 0
        z2 = z2 - y2[i]

    else:
        result[i] = y2[i]- z2
        if z2-y2[i]<0:
            break
        z2 = z2 - y2[i]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop checks `if y[i] < x` correctly, but then assigns the obviously negative difference instead of zero to the result. The next line should read

```
result[i] = 0
```

That being said, if you are using loops with numpy, you are not using the power of numpy. You can do this in a fully vectorized manner if you observe the following:

1. The sum of the first `n` elements of `y` to be set to zero must be less than or equal to `x`.
2. The following element is to be decremented by the difference.

You can compute the running sum using `np.cumsum`:

```
s = np.r_[y2, x].cumsum()
```

Appending `x` to `y2` ensures that the cumulative sum will exceed `x` at some point for sure.

Find the first element where the sum exceeds `x`:

```
n = (s >= x).argmax()
```

Now set the initial elements to zero and subtract the remainder:

```
y2[:n + 1] = 0
y2[n] -= x - s[n]
```